# Google Chrome extension Temporary files' location

Tags: javascript, html, macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

It's been more than 3 hours that I've been looking for the exact location (under OS X 10.6.8), but still can't find it.

I'm using [PageSpeed Insights](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pagespeed-insights-by-goo/gplegfbjlmmehdoakndmohflojccocli) and try to find where e.g. the temporary compressed images are being stored.

The "web" location shown in chrome is :

`filesystem:chrome-extension://gplegfbjlmmehdoakndmohflojccocli/temporary/some-file-name`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Extension folders can be reached through this:
Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/extensionguid

You can then browse through the specific folder.

Comment: I don't think the files will be in there (notice the `filesystem:` prefix). The files are stored in the sandboxed filesystem for the domain `chrome-extension://gplegfbjlmmehdoakndmohflojccocli` (which means they are obfuscated somewhere inside the Google\Chrome data-folder.